# Reusing LESS mixin classes within optional components

Tags: css, module, less, mixins

The use case: an application that splits functionality in "plugins". Something like WordPress (observer pattern). Each plugin can also have its own javascript, CSS.

There's a "core" plugin on which most of the others depend on. It comes with a file that contains LESS mixins. Example:

```
.flex-container(){
  display: -ms-flexbox;     // ie 10
  display: -webkit-box;     // safari 6-
  display: -webkit-flexbox; // safari 6+
  display: -webkit-flex;   
  display: flex;           
}
```

If I make use of that within plugins I get a lot of repetitive code:

```
.traffic-box{
  .flex-container(); // all the properties above get added here in the compiled CSS 
}

.comment-box{
  .flex-container(); // again...
}
```

Is there some way to get better compiled CSS, but without having to apply the class in the plugin HTML? I'd like to avoid using the mixin-type classes in the HTML to make it easier to change styles in the future. For example, changing that element from flex display to anything else using just CSS.

Essentially I'm asking if I can keep the modular structure and have lesscss produce:

```
.flex-container, .traffic-box, .comment-box{
  display: ...
}
```

Comment: Looks like you are looking for `extend`. Is [this](http://codepen.io/hari_shanx/pen/ayjlI) what you are looking for?

Comment: As per @Harry http://lesscss.org/features/#extend-feature

Comment: However, the only problem with that approach is that I don't think we can extend parametric mixins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per Harry's comments we can use [extend](http://lesscss.org/features/#extend-feature) to do this, the only caveat being you must change flex-container to a class from a mixin.

**Example**

```
// This now becomes a class
.flex-container{
  display: -ms-flexbox;     // ie 10
  display: -webkit-box;     // safari 6-
  display: -webkit-flexbox; // safari 6+
  display: -webkit-flex;   
  display: flex;           
}

.traffic-box{
  &:extend(.flex-container);
}

.comment-box{
  &:extend(.flex-container);
}
```

Comment: No, this seems to do exactly what I wanted. Thanks!